# Unclickable Link on Flag Summary/Review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

https://music.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/10938

On "Flags for [Username]" at the top, my username is formatted as a link, but unclickable - it's a proper link on other sites. (looks like the header is overlapping the content div, if that would make a difference?)

Edit:

A link everyone can see, it's the same effect on the "Review" title here:
https://music.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: Actually I'm seeing similar behavior with post titles as well, only the very bottom of the text is clickable.

Comment: asked a question specifically about the link [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/the-header-is-preventing-question-links-to-be-clickable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This issue has been corrected and will be corrected in the next production build.

Comment: that was rather quick