# The header is preventing question links to be clickable

Tags: bug, design

As noted by Matthew Read [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/unclickable-link-on-flag-summary-review-page#comment5467_2440), it seems links are partly unclickable. I'd blame the header:

[image]

From [this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8761) question, apparently it's the same with revisions:

[image]

And come to think of it, probably the same everywhere.